# Is there a way to make \eqref use the font weight from the current text font?

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, bold

The command `eqref` from `amsmath` does not inherit the font weight from the current font. In particular, the command `\textbf` has no effect on it. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
  1=1
  \label{my_eqn}
 \end{equation}

\noindent
Here is \verb|\textbf{(\ref{my_eqn})}|:\\ 
\textbf{(\ref{my_eqn})}
\\ (Boldfaced, as expected.)\\ 
And here is \verb|\textbf{\eqref{my_eqn}}|:\\ 
\textbf{\eqref{my_eqn}}
\\ (Not boldfaced!)

\section{Inside a section title: (\ref{my_eqn}) and \eqref{my_eqn}}

So, inside the section title as well, \verb|\ref| is boldfaced but \verb|\eqref| is not.
\end{document}
```

Output:

---

[image]

---

Is there a way to make `\eqref` use the font weight from the current text font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\eqref` is, in total

```
\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
```

and the main function of `\textup` and the internal `\tagform@` is to force the document equation style over-riding the current font, so to get what you want the simplest way would be to redefine it to

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}
```

If you want to inherit the font weight but not inherit italic or other font shapes.

Comment: @Mico no it explictly does not does that as it removes `\textup` as the question asked to inherit the current font, so there it inherits italic. (you could of course put `\textup` back if that is required.

Comment: @Mico added that version (well `\textup` to match the ams version rather than `\upshape`)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than modify the definition of `\eqref`, mess about with the `amsmath` internal `\tagform@` macro, or use the machinery of the `mathtools` package to create an entirel new tag form, I'd like to suggest that you load the `cleveref` package and use its `\labelcref` macro instead of `\eqref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{my_eqn} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\verb|(\ref{my_eqn})|: (\ref{my_eqn}) --- Normal font weight, as expected.
 
\verb|\labelcref{my_eqn}|: \labelcref{my_eqn} --- Also normal font weight.

\medskip
\verb|\textbf{(\ref{my_eqn})}|: \textbf{(\ref{my_eqn})} --- Boldfaced.
 
\verb|\textbf{\labelcref{my_eqn}}|: \textbf{\labelcref{my_eqn}} --- Also boldfaced.

\section{Cross-refs inside a section title: (\ref{my_eqn}) and \labelcref{my_eqn}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While your answer is arguably more practical (in fact, I already ended up using `cleveref` for other reasons anyway), David Carlisle's answer more strictly addresses the question as it was written, so I think I'll have to accept his answer. I wish I could accept both, though!